# How to consume a rabbitmq stream starting from the last message in the stream?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'd like to implement something with a similar behaviour to MQTT's "Retained Message".  IE I want to attach a consumer and immediately start reading from the most recent message sent.  It looks like [Rabbitmq Streams](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html) should give me what I'm looking for.

I'm a little stuck because its possible to set the offset to `last` ([see here](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2021/09/rabbitmq-streams-offset-tracking/)) which begins reading from the last *block* of messages.  But what I am looking for is the last message.

That is: I can't see how to determine which is the last message currently in the block when I subscribe.

Is there a way to set the offset to the last message in the stream?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it is not possible to determine the last message in a specific chuck.

This is because the clients don't expose all the chunk information.

When you select `last` you get the last `chunk`. The chunk itself contains the number of messages. This information atm is not exposed.

You are using PIKA so amqp way, but to have more control in the stream, you could use native clients that give you more control.

See [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stream-core-plugin-comparison.html) for more details.

You can also track the message offset to restart consuming from a specific offset. See, for example, the [java client](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-stream-java-client/stable/htmlsingle/#consumer-manual-offset-tracking)

We could add that info.